# Binding Context not working Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

there is no error in console, I've tried many things but cannot understand the     actual problem with code. Can anybody help me in this.. and  emulator snippets and code below:

home.ts:

```
enter code here
import {EventData,Observable} from "data/observable";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
var page : Page;
var tempSessions = [
{
    id:"0",
title:"session 0"
},{
    id:"1",
    title:"session 1"
},{
    id:"2",
    title:"session 2"
}];
export function pageLoaded(args:EventData) {
  page = <Page>args.object;
  page.bindingContext = new Observable({
  sessions:tempSessions
  });
}
```

home.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" load="pageLoaded">
      <GridLayout rows="auto,*">
        <!--row 0-->
        <StackLayout></StackLayout>
        <!--row 1-->
        <GridLayout rows="auto,*" row="1">
          <ListView items="{{ sessions }}">
            <ListView.itemTemplate>
              <Label text="item"/>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </GridLayout>
      </GridLayout>
    </Page>
```

[emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR0Zi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found several issues in your code. The first one is that the page event is called `loaded` instead `load`. The second one is that you could use [ObservableArray Module](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/data/observable-array), which would auto update the ListView when you push new item in the array. You could review the NativeScript [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-0)
main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <GridLayout rows="auto,*">
    <!--row 0-->
    <StackLayout row="0">
      <Label text="sample text" textWrap="true" />
    </StackLayout>
    <!--row 1-->
    <GridLayout rows="*" row="1">
      <ListView row="0" items="{{ sessions }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
          <StackLayout>
              <Label text="{{title}}"/>
          </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
  </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts

```
import {EventData,Observable} from "data/observable";
import {ObservableArray} from "data/observable-array";
import {Page} from "ui/page";
var page : Page;
var tempSessions = new ObservableArray();

export function pageLoaded(args:EventData) {
    tempSessions.push({
    id:"0",
title:"session 0"
});
tempSessions.push({
    id:"1",
    title:"session 1"
});
tempSessions.push({
    id:"2",
    title:"session 2"
});
  page = <Page>args.object;
  page.bindingContext = new Observable({
  sessions:tempSessions
  });
}
```